# launch/restrict iphone inapp mail in landscape mode

Tags: iphone, email, landscape, restrict

My app is landscape.  I would like to launch the in-app email composer in landscape and restrict it as such.  Can anyone advise how to do this?  I created a view controller with the proper auto-rotate settings to keep my app in landscape but am unsure how to tell the MFMailComposeViewController to please launch in landscape and stay there (and stop making the keyboard rotate).

Help?

Comment: Ok, so I subclassed the controller and set the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation properly which invokes the mail sheet to show correctly.  However, the keyboard that pops up when I touch the mail sheet shows up portrait sometimes and then will rotate to landscape and stay there.  How would I tell it to not bring that keyboard up in portrait?

Answer (score 0):

**This is answering his comment and not the original question.**
I had this problem as well and this snippet seems to work for me:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
```

Answer (score 0):

First Add following property in info.plist file

Supported interface orientations
            "Landscape (right home button)"

than use presentModalViewController

```
-(void)displayComposerSheet 
{ 

MFMailComposeViewController *picker4 = [[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init]autorelease];

picker4.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[picker4 setSubject:result];

CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0,0,480,320);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);  
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();    
[view.layer renderInContext:context];        

// Fill out the email body text

[self presentModalViewController:picker4 animated:NO];


}
```